# Should I delete my question?

Tags: support

I wrote a nautical vocabulary question ELU, and then realized that people with practical experience about boating might be able to answer it better over on Great Outdoors.  I got [the answer I needed](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/14933/8000) there (in a comment to the answer, actually).  I think this means I should delete the question here.  Is that right?

I would be okay with leaving both, and posting links at each to the other, but I'm afraid I may get in trouble at some point, so I'm asking now, before I get in trouble.

(The other question got closed, by the way.  But the responses I got there were more useful than the ones I've gotten here, so my preference would to keep the one there.)

Comment: Just leave things as they are...and in future avoid asking ELU questions on other SE sites where they likely are  off-topic.

Comment: @Josh - Thank you.  Okay, I'll leave it alone.  (Honestly, in this case, posting at the other site worked out extremely well.)

Answer (score -1):

If you get the answer you needed, mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark under the vote section in the answer post.

**Do not delete** the question, as other users might have the same question and you post already has the answer.

Comment: If you visit the question in question, you'll see that I already accepted an answer.  The problem was that I had done a no-no, I had asked two almost identical (if I remember right) questions on two different sites.  I followed Josh's advice provided in a comment.